# its it possible to have two ELSEIF clauses in a IF ternary?

Tags: php

can this be made into an IF ternary to shorten the code? I don't know how to do it with multiple elseif clause

```
if ($ext == "m") {
 $extype = "mp3";
}elseif ($ext == "w") {
 $extype = "wav";
}elseif ($ext == "a"){
 $extype = "aac";
}
```

the is the full function

```
function loc($id,$type,$ext) //loc($id,'n',$ext) 
{
  if (($query = mysql_query("SELECT loc FROM names WHERE id = '".(int)$id."'")) !== false)
  {
    if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0)
     if ($ext == "m") {
     $extype = ".mp3";
     }elseif ($ext == "w") {
     $extype = ".wav";
     }elseif ($ext == "a") {
     $extype = ".aac";
     }
      return '/rec/'.mysql_result($query,0,'loc').$id.'-'.($type=='n'?'n':'s').$extype); 

  }
  return 'Error Not Found';
}
```

Comment: do you realize you're using single '=' instead of '==' in your statements?

Comment: Btw: I think you mean if ($ext == "m").

Comment: i updated to add the full function coding. how does that look?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you'd be best off with a switch rather than IF/ELSE's

```
switch ($ext) {
    case 'm':
        $extype = '.mp3';
        break;
    case 'w':
        $extype = '.wav';
        break;
    case 'a':
        $extype = '.aac';
        break;
    default:
        $extype = '.wma';
        break;
}
```

Also, it sounds like you need to read the documentation on arrays and control structures at php.net.

Comment: actually, switch compiles to almost exactly the same code as if/elseif/elseif. So the difference is just readability.

Comment: @StasM Not exactly.  http://www.eventhelix.com/realtimemantra/basics/CToAssemblyTranslation3.htm

Comment: We're talking about PHP, not C.

Answer (score 11):

You can do it by nesting ternary operators.

**Don't do that. It will make your code unreadable and harder to maintain.**

There are far better solutions to whatever you're trying to do. For the love of everything that is good in the world, don't you dare write code like this:

`($var1 = "a") ? (a) : ((($var2 = "b") ? (b) : ((($var3 = "c") ? (c) : ((($var4 = "d") ? (d) : ((($var5 = "e") ? (e) : ((($var6 = "f") ? (f) : ((($var7 = "g") ? (g) : ((h))))))))))))));`

The person who has to maintain this will become a psycopath.

Use a [switch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php), use an [array with keys](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), do anything but this.

**Switch:**

```
function loc($id,$type,$ext) //loc($id,'n',$ext) 
{
  if (($query = mysql_query("SELECT loc FROM names WHERE id = '".(int)$id."'")) !== false)
  {
    if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0)
           switch ($ext) {
                case "m" : 
                     $exttype = ".mp3"; //Make sure you terminate your statements with the ; mark.
                     break;
                case "w" : 
                     $exttype = ".wma"; 
                     break;
                case "a" : 
                     $exttype = ".acc"; 
                     break;
                default : //All cases that didn't match.
                     $exttype = "";
                     break;
           }
           return '/rec/'.mysql_result($query,0,'loc').$id.'-'.($type=='n'?'n':'s').$extype); 
  }
  return 'Error Not Found';
}
```

The switch will match for all cases specified and has a default action ones that it didn't match (example: you have a "O" in that variable, then the string becomes a blank value)

**Arrays**

```
function loc($id,$type,$ext) //loc($id,'n',$ext) 
{

 $list["m"] = ".mp3";
 $list["w"] = ".wma";
 $list["a"] = ".acc";

  if (($query = mysql_query("SELECT loc FROM names WHERE id = '".(int)$id."'")) !== false)
  {
    if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0)
         $extype = $list[$ext];
         return '/rec/'.mysql_result($query,0,'loc').$id.'-'.($type=='n'?'n':'s').$extype); 

  }
  return 'Error Not Found';
}
```

This array method consumes a bit more memory because the array gets stored, but by specifying the key to the array and matching it with it's value you get that value out of it. The down side being you need to program around a default for items that are NOT in the array (again, if you have the variable with "O", it's not going to find a matching array key-value pair and come up as an error).

Comment: Thank you for posting this answer, for the good of our sanity as developers.

Comment: thanks. could $list[""] = ".wma"; be used as a default or is switch better for defaulting?

Comment: No, the key of an array doesn't work like that. It matches whatever that variable is to exactly one value. Your line in the comment would only return WMA on an empty string, meaning $ext holds no value, and you haven't avoided the issue of accounting for 'o', or any other letter. You should read over the man page on arrays and research some tutorials if you intend to use them.

Comment: @babonk is right in that switch-cases allow for defaults. Probably a better option for you to use at this point in time. Using the array isn't always the answer just because it looks like less lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

There's this thing called a "[switch](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)" statement.

Don't be afraid of it - it's your friend.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, but I wouldn't recommend it:

```
echo (($ext == "m") ? $extype = "mp3" : (($ext == "w") ? $extype = "wav" : (($ext == "a") ? $extype = "aac" : '')));
```